# JAVA read properties file multiple times for property changes

Tags: java, mule

I have a requirement that needs to read properties files from given location. The trigger is a quartz job, and in a long running process

In this scenario:
Let's say the job is triggered every 10 minutes.

```
1:00AM trigger1  -> read config.properties -> other logic

1:10AM trigger2 -> read config.properties -> other logic
```

One of our requirements is we need be able to change the values in config.properties in between trigger 1 and 2, to make sure 2 is using different config with 1.

I tried this with both java Properties class and apache commons configuration libs, and found once the properties file is read from the first time job is triggered, all the following properties file read won't pick the later changes in that file. Is this by design of those java libs or I'm testing in wrong way?

Comment: Can you post some code? Would help

Comment: Sample code required.

Comment: There is `ResourceBundle.clearCache()` - to be avoided I think. Example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819999/how-to-clear-resourcebundle-cache). However it might be something else. A modification time that is not `volatile`, and no change detected or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First answer: there shouldn't be any problem doing this. All you need to do is to provide "hooks" into your application that drive your application to **re-open** the properties file; to **re-read** the content and to then **update**/**rebuild** the Properties object that your application is relying on. There is nothing conceptually preventing this - I have coded such solutions in the past.

But, second thought: I doubt that this is a **robust** design in the long term. You see, when I made my properties "re-loadable", that was for testing purposes only. I wanted to be able to quickly changing timeout values for example; without the need to restart our whole stack.

What you want to do here is completely different. You want to "hijack" a mechanism that was never intended for such use cases to enable periodic, asynchronous updates. My initial gut feeling: don't do that. What happens if you update the properties while the file is written? What happens if updates come in very short after each other?

If you want that external sources influence the behavior of your application, than design a robust solution for **that requirement**. Don't assume that you have to override property files, just because property files are what controls your application today.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure how you are referring the file but One thing I can say here is use of protocol for getting config.properties i.e. classpath: vs file:

If you are reading file as `classpath:config.properties` then I think it will always get the very first version of the properties file that existed when classpath was loaded.

Try using file protocol - `file://var/mule/config.properties`, in that case it will always be a fresh read from file system.

May be post you code for us to see.